# Commerce: Change cart line item dynamically on checkout page

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm trying to substitute cart line items on the checkout page based on a custom input element, say a radio button. The requirement is to refresh the checkout page dynamically to reflect the new line item. Here's my approach:

- Alter form `commerce_checkout_form_checkout`
- Add custom input element with an `#ajax` setting
- In ajax callback, substitute order line items using the following:

  ```
  $order = commerce_order_load($form_state['order']->order_id);
  $product_replacement = commerce_product_load_by_sku($sku);
  $line_item_replacement = commerce_cart_product_add_by_id($product_replacement->product_id);
  commerce_cart_order_product_line_item_delete($order, $line_item_wrapper->line_item_id->value());
  $form_state['order'] = commerce_order_status_update($order, 'cart', TRUE);
  commerce_order_save($form_state['order']);
  ```
- Update order contents pane using the following:

  ```
  $pane_id = 'cart_contents';
  $checkout_pane = commerce_checkout_pane_load($pane_id);
  if ($callback = commerce_checkout_pane_callback($checkout_pane, 'checkout_form')) {
    $pane_form = $callback($form, $form_state, $checkout_pane, $order);
    if ($pane_form) {
      $form['cart_contents'] = $pane_form + array(
        '#type' => $checkout_pane['fieldset'] ? 'fieldset' : 'container',
        '#title' => check_plain($checkout_pane['title']),
        '#collapsible' => $checkout_pane['collapsible'],
        '#collapsed' => $checkout_pane['collapsed'],
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array($pane_id)),
        '#tree' => TRUE,
      );
    }
  }
  ```

Although the order contents pane does refresh to reflect the new product, an error occurs when I click "Continue to next step". Watchdog reports a `commerce_order` error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unable to get the data property commerce_total as the parent data structure is not set. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyValue() (line 442 of /var/www/mysite/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or can you suggest an alternate approach?

Comment: I have the same problem, do u find solution?